# mongoose: ObjectId returned with findOne is undefined

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to save a books document that references an artist document. However, I am not able to get the objectId from the artist document. When I try to get `_id` from the artist document I am returned `undefined`. However, if I log the entire artist document I can see that `_id` is part of the document as `_id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] }`.

How can I get ObjectId from the artists document and save the books document so it references the artist document?

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var artistSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, default: null },
});
const Artist = mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);

var bookSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    artist: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Artist' },
});
const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

// ...

let artistId = await Artist.findOne({ name: 'John Smith'})._id;
console.log(artistId); // prints: undefined

let book = new Book({
    name: 'Book Name',
    artist: artistId,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to await the async call, not the access to `_id`.  Change

```
let artistId = await Artist.findOne({ name: 'John Smith'})._id;
```

to

```
let artistId = (await Artist.findOne({ name: 'John Smith'}))._id;
```

and it should work.

As an example:

```js
function getId() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve({_id: 1}), 1000);
    });
}

async function run() {
    let id = await getId()._id;
    console.log(id);
    let id2 = (await getId())._id;
    console.log(id2);
}

run();
```